# Pass a UNIX Timestamp as a URL Segment to display entries edited since that date

Tags: query, date, date-format, entry-date, edit-date

I'm trying to create a template that will display a list of entries that have been added or edited since a particular date. The date would be passed as a UNIX timestamp in the URL like so;

mydomain.tld/entries_since/1391212800

I have tried doing something like this but I believe this is not working due to the edit_date in ExpressionEngine not being stored as a UNIX timestamp;

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="items"
    status="open"
    search:edit_date=">={segment_2}"
}
<pre>Title: {title}, URL: {url_title}, Edit Date: {edit_date format="{DATE_W3C}"}</pre>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Wondered if anyone could help? :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe, your options are:

- to change the format of date you're using on the `segment_2`, which isn't a good idea because EllisLab can some day finally normalize all date fields;
- to reformat the date to match the way its used on edit_date database column;

To change the date format, I suggest you the [Low Nice Date plugin](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-nice-date):

```
{exp:low_nice_date date="{segment_2}" format="%Y%m%d%H%i%s"}
```

Comment: Hey Robson, thanks for the link to the Low Nice Date plugin. Looks like it may not be possible to get the entries edited since a date through the standard channel entries tag. Perhaps need to write a query instead.

Comment: @doubleplusgood, really? Even using `parse="inward"` on `exp:channel:entries`?